# Entering User Credentials for Spring OAuth Authorization Code Flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am attempting to programmatically retrieve an OAuth Access Token back from my OAuth authorization server. I am able to retrieve a token using the following steps:

1. Direct browser to [http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?client_id=clientId&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:10000/client/landing](http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?client_id=clientId&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/close/hello) This endpoint requires authentication to access, so the browser is redirected to a login form, where I enter a user name & password that are validated by a custom user details service I wrote.

   2. Browser is now on a page that verifies what scopes I want to give the client access to for my protected resources. I make my selection and hit the authorize button.
   3. Browser is now redirected to the provided redirect uri with the authorization code as a query parameter. (Ex.  http://localhost:10000/client/landing?code=J23Dxx)
   4. I then take the code parameter and use it in a POST (in postman) to the /oauth/token endpoint. (Ex. localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&username=clientId&password=clientSecret&code=J23Dxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:10000/client/landing)
   5. This returns an access token, and all is good.

The issue arises when try to access the token using a OAuth2RestTemplate from my client app. Here is my client config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class ClientConfig {

@Value("${app.clientId}")
private String clientId;

@Value("${app.clientSecret}")
private String clientSecret;

@Value("${app.resourceId}")
private String resourceId;

@Value("${app.clientAuthUri}")
private String clientAuthUri;

@Value("${app.tokenUri}")
private String tokenUri;

@Value("${app.directUri}")
private String redirectUri;

@Bean
public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails getResourceDetails() {
    AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails details = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
    details.setId(resourceId);
    details.setClientId(clientId);
    details.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
    details.setScope(Arrays.asList("read", "write"));
    details.setUserAuthorizationUri(clientAuthUri);
    details.setAccessTokenUri(tokenUri);
    details.setPreEstablishedRedirectUri(redirectUri);
    details.setUseCurrentUri(false);
    return details;
}

@Autowired
private OAuth2ClientContext oAuth2ClientContext;

@Bean
public OAuth2RestOperations oAuthTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext clientContext) {
      OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(getResourceDetails(), oAuth2ClientContext); 
      return template; 
}
}
```

Then I attempt to get an access token using the OAuth rest template:

```
@Service
public class OAuthService {

@Autowired
private OAuth2RestOperations oauthTemplate;

public OAuth2AccessToken getToken() {
    return oauthTemplate.getAccessToken();
}
}
```

Running the getToken() method results in an InsufficientAuthenticationException, which makes sense, because I have not entered a username & password to access the oauth/authorize endpoint. But since I am using an authorization code flow, setting a username & password on the resource details is not an option. I have tried getting a token after going to the oauth/authorize endpoint in the same manner, but in that case I get an error about a possible CSRF attack, which I believe is due to the authorization server expecting a state parameter on the token request. Since the oauth/authorize endpoint was hit with the browser and the token endpoint hit from the OAuth2RestTemplate, no state is preserved from the authorization.

How do I utilize the OAuth2RestTemplate to access my token, or are there more fundamental problems with my design which are preventing this from working?

I am surprised that I am not finding more information about this. Am I wrong in believing that requiring authentication for the authorize & token endpoints is recommended practice? What is the standard way to utilize the OAuth2RestTemplate in a case where authentication is necessary before the resource details would be considered?